# Ubuntu firewall is blocking metatrader from install

Tags: server, wine, proxy, https

I want to install `metatrader` through `wine` but they say that there's a firewall so they keep asking for proxy server option. How i allow it to install?

Comment: It may just be missing the necessary libraries to contact the internet (e.g. try `wininet` ior `ie8` in [winetricks](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winetricks)). Otherwise it may be blocked by a software/hardware firewall elsewhere in the network (or if you are using a proxy something is not configured). If you are talking about [this thing](http://www.metatrader4.com/en) there appears to be a [linux version](https://www.mql5.com/en/articles/1358)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu firewall `ufw` is disabled by default.  If you have enabled it, use

`sudo ufw disable` to disable it again.

You can always check ufw status by typing `sudo ufw status verbose`.

Comment: is it the only protection firewall i can disable ? because metatrader keep asking for proxy server option even after i did that

Comment: Yes,  ufw is the only preinstalled firewall on Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

The mentioned error has nothing to do with firewall. I have faced with it both in Ubuntu and Windows.

Based on my experience (3 installation), the only way to get rid of this error is to just cancel installation and starting it again and again.

To be more in safe margin, configure wine for Windows XP compatibility.

Best of luck

Answer (score -1):

Firewall has nothing to do here, you need proper windows http library. Try winbind:

```
sudo apt install winbind
```

Comment: Hi. While this might theoretically answer the question, please [edit] your question to add some more details.  Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't solve the issue at all.